# "The expression \"fields(select\" is not valid."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

With Graph Explorer, the following call works just fine.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com,964f1605-0c35-4e79-bc57-cd76f7a2ff7d,4e13a384-18bc-49c0-8f21-1a3f15c4dc63/lists/d136b6b0-69a3-4f58-9ec2-3056e149b86f/items?expand=fields
```

However, when making the call with *select* like below, it fails.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com,964f1605-0c35-4e79-bc57-cd76f7a2ff7d,4e13a384-18bc-49c0-8f21-1a3f15c4dc63/lists/d136b6b0-69a3-4f58-9ec2-3056e149b86f/items?expand=fields(select=id)
```

It returns:

```
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": "The expression \"fields(select\" is not valid.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "eda74444-8c72-1111-90ea-26797ce181be",
        "date": "2020-03-18T11:11:11"
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the request?

Comment: The 2nd request failed with the Graph Explorer preview. It works with non-preview Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Use $expand=fields($select=id). The [$ prefix is mandatory for v1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters).

Comment: when using "$expand=fields($select=id)"  I get "       "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Found an unbalanced bracket expression.""

Comment: @OferGal please provide request or correlation id and timestamp for the failed request.

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/bae47d89-7e7d-40f2-b0cf-52ddb035adfa/Lists('User Information List')/items?expand=fields($select=id) returns    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": "The expression \"fields($select\" is not valid.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-07-14T22:08:48",
            "request-id": "2cc746f3-e576-4a6c-a7bd-bfdfea184441"
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the = with %3D within the nested select. Seems like Graph Explorer doesn't like a naked = in brackets. [Receiving 400s and 500s when attempting to get singleValueExtendedProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62686415/receiving-400s-and-500s-when-attempting-to-get-singlevalueextendedproperties)