# Receiving 400s and 500s when attempting to get singleValueExtendedProperties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

trying to add extended properties to calendar objects. I am able to create calendars with the following payload (Ruby syntax, payload is sent as a JSON):

```
name: build_calendar_name,
singleValueExtendedProperties: [{
  id: "String {#{SecureRandom.uuid}} Name setting_id",
  value: @setting_id.to_s
}]
```

I receive a 201 from this request and the calendar is created no problem

The frustrating part is I cannot retrieve the extended property when making a GET request. The following two requests should work:

```
GET /me/events/calendar_id?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {guuid} Name setting_id')

Response
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Found an unbalanced bracket expression.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-07-01T22:38:14",
            "request-id": "<hidden>"
        }
    }
}
```

```
GET /me/calendars?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {guuid} Name setting_id' and ep/value eq 'setting_id')

Response:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-07-01T22:40:15",
            "request-id": "<hidden>"
        }
    }
}
```

Guuid, calendar_id and setting_id are dummy values, real values are used when attempting these calls.

We've also tried following the examples verbatim at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example and still receive these response codes. Would love some help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting this on a calendar, or on an event? Your first request is retrieving an event, but your payload in the first example looks like a calendar. Also, have you tried this in Graph Explorer to rule out your Ruby code?

Comment: Crap. Sorry for the confusion, that should've been calendar. And yes, these responses are from the Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reproduced this for the `$expand` case in Graph Explorer. The problem seems to be the `=` inside the parentheses. If you URL-encode that to `%3D` the query works fine.

```
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter%3Did eq 'String {guuid} Name setting_id')
```

For the `$filter`, I reproduce it when doing `GET /me/calendars`, but not when doing `GET /me/events`. This seems to be a problem with the service (unless the docs are just wrong). Let me check and report back.

Comment: I'll give this a shot now.

Comment: That was the secret sauce!!

Comment: @crice1988 if this helped then please mark the answer as accepted, it helps others

Jason, you're a legend, you solved my issue too :)

Comment: @GavinB likewise. If this question helped, please upvote. Thanks.

Comment: @jason-johnston this no longer seems to be working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just ran this in Graph Explorer with no problem.